# When swiping between spaces, sometimes the background moves and sometimes it doesnt

Tags: macos, spaces

Since upgrading to Sierra I've noticed that sometimes when I swipe between spaces the background image moves left or right as I swipe along with whatever icons I have on my desktop and whatever (lets say) open finder windows I have. Other times the background remains static but everything else moves left or right as I swipe.

I have the same (default) bg image for all spaces.

I have also noticed that the behavior seems to remembered by the space I am moving to/from. For instance, right now I have 2 full screen spaces and then 4 "desktop" spaces and then 2 more full screen spaces. And if I swipe into or out of the desktop 4 space then the bg remains static, but swiping to any other space, the background moves.

I realize this is not a big deal, but it's annoying... thoughts?

Comment: This might be a bit too late, but I had the same experience a few days ago. I just restarted my mac for software installation and the effect is gone. For the past few days, whenever I switch spaces, the background stays static, not moving, only the other space i'm moving to, slides into the view, unlike the normal perception of the whole spaces being moved out. I couldn't find how to enable it back again. Any idea why it happen and how to enable it?

Comment: This happens all the time for me on Sierra, on both my work and personal MacBook Pros.

Comment: Happens to me to. The issue appears to be tied to individual spaces, as creating new ones do not have the issue, and sometimes individual ones snap out of it.

Comment: It's possible that this has been fixed in High Sierra ... I haven't seen it happen since upgrading. Anyone else?

Comment: You might try using the app WhichSpace. This app will display space number in menu bar.  I use it with High Sierra and I have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have this exact same problem. It usually resolves itself after a reboot or removing the affected space but is slight annoying as it does consistently happen after a few hours of uptime.